# Get text from between two patterns every time they show

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I am attempting to scrape an html file using Unix commands. I need to extract the innerhtml text from two tags which I've been representing as regexs. The trick is I need to get the innerhtml text every time this pattern of appear.

Example:

```
<p class = "someClass"> Text I need to get </p>

<p class = "someClass"> Some more I need to get </p>

<p class = "someClass"> Even more text I need to get </p>
```

Each of these paragraph tags are on a different, single line, while all of the lines are in the same file.

I can't come to a solution. Please help if you can.

Comment: When posting a question asking for a script to find specific text in a file, don't just include text that you want to be found or a useless "solution" like `cat file` will produce the expected output. [edit] your question to show the lines you want to find in context with lines you do not want to find and include the expected output given that input. Also, include rainy day cases,not just sunny day, or you'll get a solution that only works for sunny day cases and fails at some point on your real input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grep**

Cool small trick

```
grep -oP "(?<=>)[^<]*" file
```

> -P option to grep is gnu-only and experimental

or just

```
grep -oP '(?<=<p class = "someClass"> ).*?(?= </p>)' file
```

**sed**

```
sed -n 's:.*<p class = "someClass">\(.*\)</p>.*:\1:p' file
```

Comment: Ok that works nicely, but, how can I alter it so that the whole tag and its attributes are included in the pattern (i.e., "<p class = "someClass">" to "</p> as opposed to just ">" to "<") with grep?

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't seem neccesary but here it is: `grep -oP '(?<=<p class = "someClass"> ).*?(?= </p>)' file` added it in the answer

Comment: You should mention that the `-P` option to grep is gnu-only and experimental so YMMV wrt whether it works consistently or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have.

inner.txt will have your input.

```
cat inner.txt | awk -F">" '{print $2}' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//g;s/<\/p//g'
```